# C++ Using Gdiplus in Code::Blocks with MinGW compiler

Tags: c++, windows, dll, linker, gdi+

**My development environment:**
Windows 7 64bit
Code::blocks 13.12 with MinGW compiler.
Changed settings in Code::blocks - only in settings -> compiler -> linker settings -> other linker options: `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++`

**This is my failed code:**
Main:

```
#include "main.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <Gdiplus.h>


using namespace std;
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib")


MainCode /// Look better even then main() :).
{

    Execute_InitializeWindow; /// Initialize root window (For WinGUI)



    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
           0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
           szClassName,         /* Classname */
           "Code::Blocks Template Windows App",       /* Title Text */
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, /* default window */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
           544,                 /* The programs width */
           375,                 /* and height in pixels */
           HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
           NULL,                /* No menu */
           hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
           NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
           );



    Graphics* hGraphics = Graphics::FromHWND(hwnd,false); /// <---------------- HERE IT FAILS!


    /// Massage handler
    while (1){ if (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0) <= 0) {break;}

        /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        //cout << msg << endl;
        /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }


    return msg.wParam; // The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave
}



LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);

    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {


            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;
        default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            //cout << 1;
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Heder for the main code (named as main.h):

```
#include <windows.h>




/// ---------------------------------------- Codes for Initialize of main GUI -----------------------------------------

#define MainCode int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpszArgument,int nCmdShow)

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM); // Declare Windows procedure

TCHAR szClassName[ ] = "my_program_root_name";


#define Execute_InitializeWindow                        \
                                                        \
    MSG msg;                                            \
                                                        \
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;                                   \
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;                    \
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;                  \
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;                \
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                           \
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);                 \
                                                        \
                                                        \
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);     \
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);   \
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);       \
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                          \
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                               \
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                               \
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;    \
                                                        \
    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl)) {return 1;}          \



/// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Problem:**
Failing in line `Graphics* hGraphics = Graphics::FromHWND(hwnd,false);`

When I try to run this, I get this error:

```
mingw32-g++.exe   -c "D:\גיבויים\DATA\Desktop\cpp gdi plus problem\main.cpp" -o "D:\גיבויים\DATA\Desktop\cpp gdi plus problem\main.o"
mingw32-g++.exe  -o "D:\גיבויים\DATA\Desktop\cpp gdi plus problem\main.exe" "D:\גיבויים\DATA\Desktop\cpp gdi plus problem\main.o"  -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++  
D:\גיבויים\DATA\Desktop\cpp gdi plus problem\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7Gdiplus11GdiplusBasenwEj[__ZN7Gdiplus11GdiplusBasenwEj]+0xd): undefined reference to `GdipAlloc@4'
D:\גיבויים\DATA\Desktop\cpp gdi plus problem\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7Gdiplus11GdiplusBasedlEPv[__ZN7Gdiplus11GdiplusBasedlEPv]+0xd): undefined reference to `GdipFree@4'
D:\גיבויים\DATA\Desktop\cpp gdi plus problem\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7Gdiplus8GraphicsC1EP6HWND__i[__ZN7Gdiplus8GraphicsC1EP6HWND__i]+0x3a): undefined reference to `GdipCreateFromHWNDICM@8'
D:\גיבויים\DATA\Desktop\cpp gdi plus problem\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7Gdiplus8GraphicsC1EP6HWND__i[__ZN7Gdiplus8GraphicsC1EP6HWND__i]+0x57): undefined reference to `GdipCreateFromHWND@8'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
```

I spend a lot of time on it .. I do not know what to do. I realized that I need "def" file for Gdiplus.
I found this: https://sourceforge.net/u/earnie/winapi/winapi/ci/master/tree/lib/gdiplus.def

And I tried to add it in the linker settings by adding this (in compiler -> linker settings -> other linker options): `-def gdiplus.def` .
In this case the error was the same but this time with something different -
during compile time, It prints lots of error about extracting functions from the dll. it failed to extract all functions from the dll. All failures with the same error message `... symbol not definded`

I feel a little lost .. I looked for solutions on Google but it did not help .. I am very new in C ++

Thanks for helpers!

Comment: Just FYI, `#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib")` is a neat trick with Microsoft's compiler, but it doesn't work with MinGW or other compilers. You need to explicitly add the library to your project's settings. Aside from that, your code makes little sense. There is no reason to create a GDI+ drawing surface in the main method, before the window has even been displayed on the screen. Painting should occur in response to `WM_PAINT` messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `-lgdiplus` to your linker options.

Comment: No but some time after I wrote this I discovered a solution that I did not found on Google. -
The solution is to add "libgdiplus.a" in settings -> compiler -> linker settings -> link libraries.

It solved that error. I also tested your solution and it also solved the error.
Now the problem is not "missing function". it is something else.

My program now crashes in line "Graphics* hGraphics = Graphics::FromHWND(hwnd,true);"

Is it something I did wrong with the function or that it is still related to MinGW / code::blocks ?

Comment: " I also tested your solution and it also solved the error." , "This does not provide an answer to the question." oO ?